# Как заставить QML отображать custom Model если её заполнение(с предварительным подключением к бд) осуществляется из самого GUI?

Tags: qt5, qml

К примеру у меня есть моя модель берущая свои данные из какой-то базы данных. Тогда следующий код при условии, что база данных будет иметь активное соединение позволит в слое QML мне отобразить эту модель.

```
QSqlDatabase db;
//здесь будет к примеру коннект
MyModel* myModel = new MyModel(this,db);

QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("myModel", myModel);
```

Однако если, я захочу к примеру осуществить коннект к базе данных после регистрации контекста, то мне уже ничто не поможет отобразить эту модель. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как заставить QML видеть мою модель, если её заполнение с предварительным коннектом  к базе осуществляется позже и к примеру по какой-нибудь кнопке из самого GUI???

Comment: А почему после регистрации контекста у Вас не получится заполнить модель? Они же динамиечские - добавили туда данные, View обновилась. В чём проблема заполнить модель в результате нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: Заведите QObject, зарегистрируйте его в контексте, и сделайте у него два Q_INVOKABLE метода - один пусть заполняет модель из бд, а второй возвращает вам эту модель. И всё. В Qml в обработчике нажатия на кнопку вызовите метод который заполняет/обновляет модель. А в Вашей `View` забиндите свойство `model` на то, что возвращает второй метод. Модель изначально пустая, а как нажмёте кнопку и она заполнится - `View` вам её отобразит